# validate file type before upload

Tags: jquery

The default jquery-file-upload function does not have any validation before uploading files.

I want to restrict the upload to only a pdf file.

I found jquery.fileupload-validate.js file in the js folder, but I do not know how to modify this file.

Please help me.
i found this lines in jquery-file-upload `$.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.options.processQueue.push(
        {
            action: 'validate',
            // Always trigger this action,
            // even if the previous action was rejected: 
            always: true,
            // Options taken from the global options map:
            acceptFileTypes: '@',
            maxFileSize: '@',
            minFileSize: '@',
            maxNumberOfFiles: '@',
            disabled: '@disableValidation'
        }`
but i do not know how to change it.

Comment: Be sure to validate the file for security on the server side as well - it's easy for a malicious user to bypass client-side checks.

Comment: If checking the extension isn't enough, using [HTML5 FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) may help as well.

Comment: I validate file type in server side.but i want validate file type on client side.

Answer (score 1):

In your js file where you validate your form or only file upload use like

```
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>

jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
  });
  $("#form").validate({
    rules:
      'image': {
        required: true
        accept: "application/pdf"
      }
   }, 
    messages: {
      "image": {
        required: "Please upload only pdf files."
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: i found this lines in jquery-file-upload ` $.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.options.processQueue.push(
        {
            action: 'validate',
            // Always trigger this action,
            // even if the previous action was rejected: 
            always: true,
            // Options taken from the global options map:
            acceptFileTypes: '@',
            maxFileSize: '@',
            minFileSize: '@',
            maxNumberOfFiles: '@',
            disabled: '@disableValidation'
        }`
but i do not know how to change it.

Comment: you do not need to change nay code in yourblueimp javascript file..just put validation where you call your file upload function

Comment: check this link for more info http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-beginner-using-blueimp-fileupload-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You accept method for validate file upload in jquery like

```
accept= "application/pdf"
```

hope this link will help yoo http://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method/

Comment: thanks.I know that .but i do not know how to modify jquery-file-upload plugin to add restrict